# Trying to get started win ASP.NET core and azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage

I'm following this guide [How to get started with Azure Table storage and Visual Studio connected services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables/). The very first code that I add:

```
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LogLevel = Microsoft.Framework.Logging.LogLevel;
```

Gives an error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Framework' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I've looked in NuGet for the `Microsoft.Framework` and couldn't find it. What am I missing here? is this guide no longer relevant?

Comment: try this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration/

Comment: As 2024, this package is now 'unlisted'. Have not yet found it's replacement

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install this framework

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Framework.Logging -Pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you have followed the get started article to add the assembly. I test on my local everything works fine. As my test, if you missing `Microsoft.Framework.Logging`, you will get the error:`The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. If you missing `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`, you will get the error:`The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. So I could not reproduce your issue. I would recommend you to check your application whether it  would work Before ‘Add Connected Services’. If you just learn how to Add Connected Services’, it is a good choice to create a new template to test.